# Notifications from Excel file modification

Tags: excel, vba, email, notifications

do someone know if it's possible to execute a VBA code that send an email or windows notification when someone modifies, add a line for example or any modification. I want to use it for a file that help us to do regular check on the number of contracts delivered. So everytime someone types a new line, I can see it and put it on my own check file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Worksheet.Change` event is what you want.  In short, whenever one of a certain type of change is made to the worksheet, this code is run.  You can read more about it on the documentation page here:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change

Comment: okay let me see

Comment: Alright i learned it, so now how i send me a notification ?

Comment: You mentioned that you want it to send an email.  There are many resources online that will show you how to send emails using VBA.  Try looking at those references, and then if you have a specific problem, ask a new question.